# Video Background Only Playing 1 Video

Tags: html, css, loops, video, background

I'm putting together a website and I have implemented a Full-screen Video Background. The problem is that I can't get it to play the next video. It only plays the first video it sees. I have tried other video formats with no prevail. Please help!

```css
/*CSS*/

video#full-screen {
            position: absolute; 
            right: 0; 
            bottom: 0;
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%; 
            width: auto; 
            height: auto; 
            z-index: -1; 
            filter: hue(100%);
            }
```

```html
<!--HTML-->

<video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="assets/Logo.png" id="full-screen">
            <source src="video/home-video.webm" type="video/webm"/>
            <source src="video/home-video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code about how are you changing the video source...

Comment: No code, I just used an online converter to change the videos format.
http://www.online-convert.com/

Comment: I still don't see the next video....for example in your example you have two video sources(basically the same video with different extensions), and that is for browser compatibility, for example, if chrome supports webm it plays the first source...if you open your website on an old firefox version that doesn't support webm then it play the mp4 file....is just that....

Comment: I am looking to get both videos to play in the browser. I want it to be a continuous loop. One video plays, and then the next. http://www.motorwerks.com/  <-- This is a website that demonstrates exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: http://slicejack.com/fullscreen-html5-video-background-css/ <-- This website shows a demonstration, in which I have been following. Here the person is using pure HTML and CSS.

Comment: After re-reading your comment I think I understand what you are saying! I should take the multiple video's and make one video from it. And then the other video formats are for browser support. I was getting myself confused ! Thanks Hackerman !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of sources is not a playlist but a set of alternative sources. Once the browser finds one that is supported, the rest are ignored. You'll have to use JavaScript to achieve what you want (independently of doing it with one or two video tags).

You could have list of videos in an array in JavaScript and update the video source accordingly instead of having multiple sources directly under the video:

Add the following within your script tag and it should work for you.

```
var myvid = document.getElementById('full-screen');
var myvids = [
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4", 
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
  ];
   //replace this array with the videos you would like to play next

var activeVideo = 0;

myvid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
  // update the new active video index
  activeVideo = (++activeVideo) % myvids.length;

  // update the video source and play
  myvid.src = myvids[activeVideo];
  myvid.play();
});
```

This JavaScript snippet will automatically change your video src to the next one in the array.

You can see this working on this JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/2976jx1s/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Rohin,
Thank you for your help man! What I did was downloaded a video merger application, took my video clips and merged them into one video file. And now my css method is working perfect. Thanks for your idea, I really appreciate your help!